# Declare generic list as member of parent class

Tags: c#

I want to create a parent class that contains a list and can do simple operations on that list (add, remove, or swap items). The type of object in the list will be different for each child class. If I make it a `List<object>` then I think I will have to do a bunch of casting in the child class (something that would be nice to avoid). Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
public abstract class Parent {
    
    protected List<T> ListOfSomeType; // <- List<T> isn't allowed
    
    protected void RemoveThing<T> (T thing) {
        ListOfSomeType.Remove(thing)
    }
    
    protected void AddThing<T> (T thing) {
        ListOfSomeType.Add(thing);
    }

    protected void SwapThings(int index1, int index2) {
        var temp = ListOfSomeType[index1];
        ListOfSomeType[index1] = ListOfSomeType[index2]
        ListOfSomeType[index2] = temp;
    }
}

public class Child1 : Parent {
    
    public Child() {
        ListOfSomeType = new List<SomeType>();
    }
}

public class Child2 : Parent { // same sort of deal with new List<SomeOtherType>()}
```

Comment: Just like a `List`, any class in C# can have generic arguments, including `Parent`. You can then share that generic argument with that class's members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you promote the type `T` to the class, then it can be used by the class members:

```
public abstract class Parent<T>
{
    protected List<T> ListOfSomeType = new List<T>();

    protected void RemoveThing(T thing)
    {
        ListOfSomeType.Remove(thing);
    }

    protected void AddThing(T thing)
    {
        ListOfSomeType.Add(thing);
    }

    protected void SwapThings(int index1, int index2)
    {
        var temp = ListOfSomeType[index1];
        ListOfSomeType[index1] = ListOfSomeType[index2];
        ListOfSomeType[index2] = temp;
    }
}
```

Then when creating `Child`, you specify the `SomeType` type when you define the `Parent` that it derives from:

```
public class Child : Parent<SomeType>
{
    public Child()
    {
        ListOfSomeType = new List<SomeType>();
    }
}
```